# How to format number using shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a text document with the following content:

```
[ForwardTimer],__fc_layer_1__,[Span:1ms970us]
[ForwardTimer],__batch_norm_2__,[Span:5ms64us]
[ForwardTimer],__batch_norm_3__,[Span:5ms87us]
```

I want to convert the time values in ms unit, like

```
[ForwardTimer],__fc_layer_1__,1.970ms
[ForwardTimer],__batch_norm_2__,5.064ms
[ForwardTimer],__batch_norm_3__,5.087ms
```

while keeping previous words unchanged.
How can I process the document using shell script, especially with sed or awk command?

Comment: Please read the description of the "shell" tag. Your question is too unspecific to answer. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: `awk -F',|:|ms|us' '{ printf "%s,%s,%d.%03dms\n", $1, $2, $4, $5 }' file` ??

Comment: @oguzismail yeah it works, thanks you a lot!

Comment: @oguzismail that will fail given an input line like `[ForwardTimer],__bus_error_1__,[Span:1ms970us]`, i.e. it'll fail given any text that contains the substrings `ms` or `us`.

Comment: @EdMorton I know, that's why I commented instead of answering. I should've mentioned that though

Comment: Based on the OPs response I don't think he picked up on that distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F '\\[Span:' '{split($2,array,"ms|us"); printf("%s%s.%03dms\n",$1,array[1],array[2])}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
[ForwardTimer],__fc_layer_1__,1.970ms
[ForwardTimer],__batch_norm_2__,5.064ms
[ForwardTimer],__batch_norm_3__,5.087ms
```

This splits your lines with `[Span:` as field separator in two parts (`$1` and `$2`). With function `split()` and `ms` or `us` as field separator it splits `$2` in three parts (`array[1]`, `array[2]` and `array[3]`). `array[3]` is unused. The formatted output then makes `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\[Span:([0-9]*)([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)[^]]*[]]/\1.\n\3\2/;:a;/\n[0-9]{3}/!s/\n/&0/;ta;s/\n//' file
```

Use pattern matching and back references to achieve the desired result.

Not forgetting to zero space the decimal part of the match using a loop and the introduced newline, which on completion is removed.

The first substitution command focuses on a string such as `[Span:5ms64us]` and if found groups the `5` in back reference 1, `ms` in back reference 2 and `64` in back reference 3. These are rearranged into `\1.\n\3\2` i.e. `5.\n64ms` and the remainder of the initial string is removed.

The second part of the sed script zero spaces the decimal part of back reference 3 to be 3 digits long with leading zeroes. Using the `\n` as a marker, if the numeric digits following the `\n` is less than 3 in length, a `0` is appended to the `\n` and the check is repeated. Once the check passes i.e. there are 3 digits, the `\n` is removed and the processing is complete.

Comment: The regex pattern makes me confused. I understand that you combine a sequence of sed operations together. Could you show me the intermediate result, or explain the regex pattern? Thanks!